# mysqldump with LIMIT and --order-by-primary

Tags: mysqldump

I want to use mysqldump to retrieve X first rows from a database (where "first" are ordered by primary key).

I'm trying to use mysqldump the following way:

`mysqldump [connection-info] -where"1=1 LIMIT 40" --order-by-primary database table >> file.sql`

(this is inside a script who runs different configurations for different tables)

Now, the problem, that command creates the following query:

`SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM`table`WHERE 1=1 LIMIT 40 ORDER BY primary_key`

Is an invalid query, I need the `LIMIT 40` to be placed after the `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: If you know the right value of 40th ID or if it goes 1-40 without gaps, you could do `--where "<idcol> <= 40"` or similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that you cant use limit in combination with `--order-by-primary`

One way around this is to define the order by within the `-where` argument. If you know the primary key for the table:

```
mysqldump -u lelle -p -w"1 = 1 order by <primary key> LIMIT 40" <database> <table>
```

Note that `<primary key>` is a place holder for the columns in the primary key.

if you don't know the primary key in advance you can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to determine that:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ',') 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY' 
  and CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = ... and table_name = ...;
```

and then use the information in mysqldump.